# Reaching JTextField in a DocumentListener

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, sudoku, documentlistener

So, I finished making a Sudoku solver but I want to improve it. To do this I somehow need to reach my `betterJTextField` from the `documentListener`. I'm using a `documentListener` to read in real-time from my `betterJTextFields`, the problem I have is that in the `insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)`.

I need to reach the `betterJTextfield` that the `DocumentEvent` happened in. For example, if invalid input, the `betterJTextfield` will turn red etc.

I have all my `betterJTextfield` in a matrix if you need to know. Every field handles one number in the Sudoku.

```
@Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

       //Removed code which checks if the input in the betterJTextField is fine. 

    }
```

(`JFormattedTextfield` extends `JTextField`)

```
public class betterJTextField extends JFormattedTextField {
private int row;
private int column;

public betterJTextField(Format format, int row, int column) {
    super(format);
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public int getRow() {
    return row;
}

public int getColumn() {
    return column;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand completely what you are asking, but I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
private static class RedDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {
    private JTextField textField;

    public RedDocumentListener(JTextField textField) {
        this.textField = textField;
    }
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        textField.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        textField.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        textField.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
}
```